# $dxdydz \to -r^2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi+\theta)dr d\phi d\theta$?

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, partial-derivative, spherical-coordinates, differential

So I got this answer $-r^2\sin \theta\sin(\phi+\theta)dr d(\phi)d(\theta)$ which I think is wrong because I googled it and it must be $-r^2\sin\theta dr d\phi d\theta,$ but $\sin(\phi+\theta$) clearly is not equal to 1 so whats wrong with my calculations? If it's wrong

https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/q89/s720x720/1374182_327112750765411_1366347789_n.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have $z = r\cos\theta$ not $z = r\cos\varphi$. For your choice of $z$ the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$ does not hold, which it should.